# Typescript, interface inside class?

Tags: typescript, class, interface, nested

I could not find any article about this.

How can i define a nested `interface` inside a `class`?

```
export class Car {

  export interface Config {
    name : string
  }

  constructor ( config : Config ) {  }

}
```

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: @SLaks you can get close enough with class-namespace merging

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't do it directly. But you can use namespace-class merging to achieve the desired effect at least from the point of you of an external consumer:

```
export class Car {


    constructor(config: Car.Config) { }
}
namespace Car {
    export interface Config {
        name: string
    }

}

let c: Car.Config;
```

Comment: Be aware that this is not recommended, and violates one of the recommended rules of tslint (old) and eslint-typescript (new ts linter).   See here https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-namespace.md

Comment: @Tom I am not a particularly big fan of that blanket removal of `namespaces`. I have seen namespaces still used in several scenarios, merging is one of them. It is a bad idea to use them instead of modules, but that is not what is going on here.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I won't speak to the merits of namespaces and modules, but I will say that I am a fan of using linting to push TS in the direction of JS developments.  TS can give us access to features years before JS, but once things are sorted out in JS, that's the direction I want to go.

Comment: @Tom the namespace here is used just for types, there is no runtime behavior, it is not even emitted to JS this is why I say in this case it is not used in a bad way, lots of modules use `namespace` as part of their definitions on DT...

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Ok, but I got the impression from the rule description that I linked that there is a JS way to do the same thing, and that is the reason for the rule.

Comment: Related: Namespaces are NOT legacy and they are not being removed from TypeScript - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30994

Comment: But what about if the class is generic and I need to reference those generic type parameters from the interface?